# Apply Jquery after Url.Action is completed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I was trying to apply jquery on particular div, but as button has

`href='@Url.Action("SomeAction","SomeController")'`

associated with it, I am not able to apply jquery on div. 
How can i apply jquery/Javascript after Url.Action method is complete???

I want to apply following jquery on click hving id ADD

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').on('click', '#Add', function (e) {

            $("#accordion").focus();
        });
    });
});
```

But as my link is as below

```
<a class="a" id="Add"  href="@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController">Add</a>
```

It adds new div and Page kind of gets reloaded and the above jquery is not applied.
I want when add is clicked new div should be added and focus should stay on it, but instead page rolls back to top.

Thanks

Comment: Since `@Url.Action` runs server-side, and JQuery runs client-side, there is no way to make JQuery run before `@Url.Action`. Thus, your question doesn't make any sense. Could you post some JQuery code, and a better description of what the problem is?

Comment: What exactly you want? Just give a example maybe there is a workaround. Also please elaborate on `apply jquery`

Comment: @Satpal updated the ques. Hope it is bit more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Make your html like below

```
<input type "button" value="buttontext" onclick="loadDetails"/>
```

Then in your javascript

```
function loadDetails() {
        alert("hello");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get('@url.action("SomeAction","SomeController")',function(data){
        $('#yourdivid').html(data);
        })
    }
```

Also don't forget instead of using   `return View("YourViewName")` use `return PartialView("YourViewName");`